# Display of a context-sensitive submenu

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I wrote a program that creates an icon in the system tray and clicking the right mouse button displays a context menu with 2 points Notes and Quit, Notes item is a submenu of the one-point Create new note. But why the item is not displayed Notes. Why?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tray = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()
    icon = app.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DesktopIcon)
    tray.setIcon(icon)
    tray.show()
    CreateMenu(tray, app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def CreateMenu(tray, app):
    m1 = QtGui.QMenu("Menu 1")
    m2 = QtGui.QMenu("Notes")
    m2.addAction("Create new note")
    m1.addMenu(m2)
    m1.addSeparator()
    m1.addAction("Quit", app.quit)
    tray.setContextMenu(m1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `m1` menu as a parent to `m2` and it will work.

```
m1 = QtGui.QMenu("Menu 1")
m2 = QtGui.QMenu("Notes", m1)
```

Tested on my Ubuntu box.